# How to dynamically instantiate a class?

Tags: c#

```
var typeName = $"Drv{id}.Fonte";
var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Drv{id} is my namespace and Fonte is the class name.

Why 'type' is always null?

When i call the third line, I get this:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does all your types compiled in the same assembly ? I mean in the current executing assembly ? If Not then you need to get the assembly first and get the type from that.

Comment: Yep. If I type Drv1.Fonte, the autocomplete works.

Comment: and is id == 1?

Comment: @SteveHarris Yep.

Comment: It works for me, can you show us your namespace how it is defined and class declaration perhaps?

Comment: Is the type generic?

Comment: @InBetween judging by the 2nd screenshot - no.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer just edited the question, hadn't seen it.

Comment: The type isn't defined in the current assembly so you need to specify the qualified name. I'm guessing its not strongly named, so, judging from your screenshots, it should be enough with `"Drv{id}.Fonte, Drv{id}`. The value after the `,` is the assembly name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this bit of code I wrote recently.  I needed to instantiate an object at runtime, like you, but came across several issues with the location of the class (different assemblies, running as vshost, running as IISExpress).

This was for a VERY generic scenario, so it may be overkill for your needs...

```
private static Type GetType(string typeName)
{
    // check executing assembly
    var type = Assembly
        .GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == typeName);

    // if not found check referenced assemblies
    if (type == null)
    {
        type = Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetReferencedAssemblies()
            .Select(Assembly.Load)
            .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == typeName);
    }

    // if still not found check all suitably named assemblies in executing folder
    if (type == null)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.dll");

        if (files.Length == 0)
        {
            files = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath, "*.dll");
        }

        files.ToList().ForEach(filename =>
        {
            if (type == null)
            {
                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(filename);
                var castableAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly.GetName());
                type = castableAssembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(x => x.FullName == typeName);
            }
        });
    }

    return type;
}
```

That will return either null or a type that you can use with `Activator.CreateInstance()` and you know it will be accessible.  In your case, change your code to...

```
var typeName = $"Drv{id}.Fonte";
var type = GetType(typeName); // using the above method
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

This is not performance friendly code, but unless you're doing this a lot, or your working directory has a tonne of assemblies you shouldn't need to worry about it.  If you are doing it a lot or you do have a tonne of assemblies then you should maybe reconsider the overall design.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 2):

I will elaborate more on the practical part.

As others said you need the assembly qualified name.
Why? Well look at the comment of `Type.GetType(string typeName)` method.

> Parameters:
>
> //   typeName:
>   //     The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See System.Type.AssemblyQualifiedName.
>
> //     ***If the type is in the currently executing assembly*** or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

Notice that only *if* type is in the currently executing assembly is sufficient to call it like you did.

I have a class in another project that is referenced by my main project just like you do.

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test2
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string CallMe()
        {
            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call it like that:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Test2;

namespace NetCore2._0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var typeName = typeof(Test2.Class1).AssemblyQualifiedName;
            var type = Type.GetType(typeName);

            Console.WriteLine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
            var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Class1;
            Console.WriteLine(myObject.CallMe());
        }

    }
}
```

I hope you can see where the difference is and why you need to supply qualified name now.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Assembly qualified name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname(v=vs.110).aspx). As mentioned on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Example (from the MSDN link):

> TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.ContainingClass+NestedClass,MyAssembly

Answer (score 1):

The format of the string you are using to instantiate the type is wrong.

From the documentation of `Type.GetType(String)`:

> typeName : String
>
> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See
>   [AssemblyQualifiedName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Type_AssemblyQualifiedName). If the type is in the currently executing
>   assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name
>   qualified by its namespace.

Source: [Type.GetType Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Type_GetType_System_String_)

From `AssemblyQualifiedName`'s documentation:

> The assembly-qualified name of a type consists of the type name,
>   including its namespace, followed by a comma, followed by the display
>   name of the assembly. The display name of an assembly is obtained
>   using the Assembly.FullName property.
>
> For example, the assembly-qualified name for a class might look like
>   this:
>
> TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.ContainingClass+NestedClass, MyAssembly,
>   Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b17a5c561934e089

Comment: Thx, I instantiate my class and call fonte.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName to know the correct format.